# Initializing JestClient when application calls multiple Elasticsearch endpoints

Tags: java, elasticsearch, singleton, jest-client

My API currently calls one Elasticsearch endpoint using JestClient. I want to add some functionality that requires calling a second, different Elasticsearch endpoint. How is this possible, when you have to specify the endpoint upon initializing JestClient?

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public JestClient jestClient() {
    JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
    factory.setHttpClientConfig(
      new HttpClientConfig.Builder("http://localhost:9200")
        .build());
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

My application design uses Singleton classes for these initializations so I'm not sure how to fix this aside from using a different Elasticsearch client for my second endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can create two clients and based on the use-case in calling classes, if you require both the clients, inject both clients or if you requires one specific client, inject that client in your class, you just need to have a different name(like clientv2 for es 2 version, and clientv5 for ES 5.x version) for your client to make it work, its easy as well, as you know your use-case and know what all versions of clients is need in your classes.

on a side note, active development of JEST is stopped long ago, and now elasticsearch provides the official java client know as [Java high level rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html), so IMHO you should switch to JHLRC to get the maximum benefit and to make future migration easy, which I think is the use-case of yours.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that makes sense. By different names do you mean using @Named annotation to pass the specific client into my accessor?

Comment: @N.A if you are known to @Named annotation it would be a best solution, otherwise you can simply create object like `ES2Client es2client = new ES2Client` and ES5Client es5client = new ES5Client(), this way you have `es2client` and `es5client` object reference which tells what version client they are and you can use them directly.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use @Named annotations to create two JestClients and inject them into their respective components

Answer (score 0):

You could create a factory and return the client depending on a parameter.
The parameter could be the url itself or just an enum that represents the endpoint.